# Oracle PL/SQL Developer vs SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I can not share the query but in out company some of us use SQL developer and others use PL/SQL Developer.
We use the same username and password but I use SQL developer and ran a specific query that took 3mins to complete. My colleague ran the same query after that amd it took 8min. I would expect to run id faster because no hard parse occures in that case but anyway 3x slower in PL/SQl developer. Is not an Oracle program but it is running and processing on the server what could make such difference?

Of course this is not the case with all queries I saw this accidently when I ran this query with more data that it took 3x fewer time as in PLSQL developer on colleague's PC

Comment: There are two execution code paths, the C based SQLNet vs the Java/JDBC. Comparing the two seems straightforward, but it's not.

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that your choice of GUI influenced the query runtime.  Far more likely possibilities

1. Random noise/ load on the system.  The quick run was quick because there were fewer sessions competing for resources and the slow run was slow because there were more sessions competing for resources.  The more virtualized your environment, the harder this can be to see (i.e. if your DB is running in a virtual machine, that virtual machine may be competing with other virtual machines for resources).  And it could be something other than the database server like the network between your client machines and the server that are the bottleneck.
2. Not exactly the same query.  If you used different values for bind variables, one query might have had to read a lot more data to return the result for one person/ account/ entity and the other might have had to read less.
3. You're measuring the time to return the first page of data, not to return the last row, and the front ends are configured to request different amounts of data in the initial result.

Comment: 1. we tried at different times and always the same result. 2. exactly same sql script. 3. no different data. it is actually insert into statement. we are populating same table with the same amount of data

Comment: @Pato You should modify the question and add that information. Or possibly add a new question since this one will probably stay closed. You should also add the precise query. And you may also want to verify through GV$SQL (based on the SQL_FULLTEXT) that both your queries are generating the same SQL_ID, or they are not really the same text. When you have the SQL_ID, you might as well also compare the execution plans with by running: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'SQL_ID'));`